# Define interface of React cloned element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component to which I pass children:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
</MyComponent>
```

At this point, `Child` doesn't have any props. But then inside `MyComponent` I'm injecting a new prop by cloning:

```
  {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (!child || !React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return null;
    }

    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      ...child.props,
      newProp: 'hello' // New prop
    });
  })}
```

Now, in the interface of Child I should define `newProp`:

```
interface Child {
  newProp: string
}
```

However, that prop isn't passed when I first use `<Child/>` inside `MyComponent`.

One workaround I thought of is to just make `newProp` optional, but it feels hackish, this prop isn't really optional.

What would be a proper way to solve it, namely have the prop in the interface of `Child` without having Typescript complaining about not passing it in `<Child/>`

Comment: Have you tried adding defaultValue such as empty string "" to a newProp prop in Child component?

Comment: @skelaw thanks for your answer, of course that will work, but making it optional is even a better solution imo, I'd like to not pass anything to Child, everything about the additional props injected later should be abstracted if possible

Comment: I am not sure but, if you define newProp as optional to Child element and then define it as a required prop to clone element you might have a chance. By using this u can create a funnel.

Comment: @Cemal How would you define it as a required prop to clone element?

Comment: I can see the required prop in your code. return React.cloneElement(child, {
      ...child.props,
      newProp: 'hello' // New prop
    }); You need to add optional prop to your Child component.

Comment: Yes, I wrote in my question that it's one workaround that is working - adding optional prop